# JavaScript: mask for numbers that allows arrows/pgup/pgdown etc

Tags: javascript

I've written simple JavaScript mask that allows you to write only numbers to input. But the thing is, when you press arrow key, the ***caret will move back to the end of the line***.

How can I ignore arrow keys, or other meta keys?

Here's my mask:

```
function applyMaskInteger(elementId) {
    var e = document.getElementById(elementId);
    e.value = e.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
}
```

PS: I like jQuery, but please answer only with plain JavaScript ... (we don't use jQuery on this project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a regular `<input type="text">`.

You can move the caret (at least in modern browsers) by altering the values of its `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties.

```
function applyMaskInteger(elementId) {
  var input = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var value = input.value;
  var caret = input.selectionEnd;

  // apply the mask
  input.value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");

  if (typeof caret !== 'undefined') {
    // count the resulting characters before the caret
    var prefix = value.substr(0, caret);
    prefix = prefix.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
    // move the caret
    input.selectionStart = prefix.length;
    input.selectionEnd = prefix.length;
  }
}
```